# Magento: register custom template files for static block widget

Tags: php, magento, templates, widget, themes

I am starting to learn how to work with Magento. I like the concept of static block and that it is so easy to add them to a cms page using the static block widget. 
The widget gives me a dropdown where I can choose what template file it should use. By default there is only the default template file located in `cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml`

Here is the dialog:
[image: Magento CMS static block widget]

**How can I add my own template files to the dropdown?**

I know that the widget only creates the following line:

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="8"}}
```

And I know that I could easly change the "template" attribute. But I think that is not a clean way as in the future, users don't know the right file name and it would be much easier for them just to use the dropdown.

I hope I could explain the problem and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer I will assume you understand how Magento extensions work, but if not there are many good answers on this topic.

Widgets are defined by widget.xml files, so you will need to add a widget.xml file to the `etc` subdirectory of a new or existing extension (i.e. `app/code/local/My/MyExtension/etc`). Since the CMS Static Block widget is already defined as `<cms_static_block>` in `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/widget.xml`, your new widget.xml file will just be injecting a new template node into the existing XML config of this widget. Here is what your new widget.xml might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <cms_static_block>
        <parameters>
            <template>
                <values>
                    <custom translate="label">
                        <value>cms/widget/static_block/custom.phtml</value>
                        <label>My Extension - Custom CMS Block Template</label>
                    </custom>
                </values>
            </template>
        </parameters>
    </cms_static_block>
</widgets>
```

As you probably already know, the `<value>` node refers to the relative location of your custom template. So in my example above, it refers to a template file here (whatever your custom package/theme dir is): `app/design/frontend/my_package/my_theme/template/cms/widget/static_block/custom.phtml`